# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 2)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

First time trying to make a fit on Python. I have sets of measurements and need to make a non-linear fit on provided data. Fit should be quadratic polynomial. Here are the code and the error:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

x = array([[0.121644, 0.243288, 0.486576, 0.60822, 0.729864, 0.851508]]).reshape(-1,1)
y = array([[0.95, 1.02, 1.21, 1.35, 1.47, 1.61]]).reshape(-1,1)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree= 2, include_bias=False)
x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)

x_val= linspace(0.121644, 0.851508, 100).reshape(-1,1)
x_vp= poly.transform(x_val)


y_val = reg.predict(x_vp)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-38d844be643a> in <module>
      9 
     10 
---> 11 y_val = reg.predict(x_vp)
     12 
     13 plt.scatter(x,y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in predict(self, X)
    223             Returns predicted values.
    224         """
--> 225         return self._decision_function(X)
    226 
    227     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    207         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    208         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 209                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    210 
    211     def predict(self, X):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    149             ret = np.dot(a, b)
    150     else:
--> 151         ret = a @ b
    152 
    153     if (sparse.issparse(a) and sparse.issparse(b)

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 2)
```

I know there the problem is in dimensions of x and x_val, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but can yet.

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree= 2, include_bias=False)
x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
```

you make the design matrix x_poly but fit the modal on x. Then you try to predict on transformed design matrix for new data, so the shapes will be different.

if i am not mistaken, it should be

```
...
reg.fit(x_poly,y)
...
```